# Speech Recognizer Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1107 "(null)")

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am creating an ios app in swift which uses speech recognizer object which is invoked at a button press. However everytime i press the button, i get this error Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1107 "(null)") and the speech recognition terminates.

I have checked other online solutions available on this such as

restarting simulator - this works for me but only for the first press of the button. any subsequent press on the button results in this error

destroying the speech recognition object after every button press. I am calling the speechrecognizer.task.cancel and speechrecognizer.task.finish functions before each new call as well as the reset button of the speech recognition object, but this doesn't work too,

Would really appreciate any kind of lead on this, thank you very much

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.